# Pandas combine duplicate columns that contain strings

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm having problems (sort of) with combining duplicate columns. It seems to work on older versions of Pandas/Python (not sure what the culprit is here), but not on the latest version.

I basically have a dataframe of mixed values with duplicate column names after a concat. The values are either going to be a int, string, or nan. All non-nan values are going to be *the same for each duplicate column name*, so in theory max() should do the trick.

Say I have the Dataframe:

```
    col1  col1  col2  col2  col3
0   Foo   nan   nan   Bar   Baz
1   nan   nan   Bar   Bar   nan
2   0     nan   1     nan   1
```

My goal is to get

```
    col1  col2  col3
0   Foo   Bar   Baz
1   nan   Bar   nan
2   0     1     1
```

Doing this

```
df.groupby(df.columns,axis=1).max()
```

Does exactly what I want it to do on a older version of Pandas/Python, but does not work for the latest. This is what I'm getting on the latest version:

```
    col1  col2  col3
0   nan   nan   Baz
1   nan   nan   nan
2   0     1     1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the logic of `max` here? `max` of what

Comment: Because the values of each column is either going to be duplicates, or nan. I'll edit that in.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess the problem arises when you try to compare strings with `np.nan`

A workaround would be to use empty string instead of `np.nan`s

```
df.fillna('').groupby(df.columns, axis=1).max()

    bar baz foo
0   Bar Baz Foo
1   Bar     
2   1   1   0
```

Can go back to having `np.nan`s afterwards if needed

```
.replace('', np.nan)

    bar baz foo
0   Bar Baz Foo
1   Bar NaN NaN
2   1   1   0
```

---

#### `edit`

If you don't want to use a workaround, or if `''` might be present in your data frame, you can *define your own max function* and use it to aggregate

```
def mmax(s):
    s = [z for z in s if not pd.isnull(z)]
    if not len(s): return np.nan
    return max(s)

def a(s):
    return(s.agg(mmax, axis=1))

df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(a)
```

Outputs

```
bar baz foo
0   Bar Baz Foo
1   Bar NaN NaN
2   1   1   0
```

Comment: `df.fillna('').groupby(df.columns, axis=1).max()` almost works, but seems to do weird things when comparing `''` with an INT. I did some extre preprocessing to get around that but it seems to work.

Comment: @jaykayrowling did you check the edit? :) You can put whatever `key` you want in `mmax` func, so that will make very flexible. From your example, seemed that a row would have only `int` (or `str`) and `np.nan`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `transpose` the dataframe firstly, `reset the index`, and then `rename` the duplicate `index` column values, and lastly use `groupby`.

```
df_t = df.T.reset_index()
df_t["index"] = df_t["index"].str.split(".").str[0]
result = df_t.groupby("index").first().T
```

output

```
Out[57]: 
index col1 col2 col3
0      Foo  Bar  Baz
1      NaN  Bar  NaN
2        0    1    1
```

Comment: He doesn't want the `first` value, but the `max` value of each row

Comment: @RafaelC I think here `max` means `first` according to his explanation. Maybe I'm wrong, but I have no idea about how to get the `max` value between string and integer.

Answer (score 0):

your algorithm is quite a good one, can you try:

```
df.groupby(df.columns,axis=1).max(axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried, failed, because `nan` will be returned when comparing `nan` with strings. so I tried `df.fillna('').groupby(df.columns,axis=1).max(axis=1)` as @RafrelC posted, that works fine.